# Angular 2 Router - Cannot access child routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
import { RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { FirstChildComponent } from './first-child.component';
import { SecondChildComponent } from './second-child.component';

export const TempRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':slug', component: SecondChildComponent },
      { path: '', component: FirstChildComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

When I try to access the '/main/rahul' URL, where rahul is the slug, the Second Child component is not loaded. Instead in web console I see a list of errors like

```
es6-shim.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
zone.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Reflect.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
system.src.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
systemjs.config.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
rahul:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined(anonymous function) @ rahul:20
bundle.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Angular Router Version : 3.0.0-alpha.7

Also, when trying to access URL: '/main/', gives me same errors as above, whereas it should load First Child Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: *Please make sure in `MainComponent`, you have used or put `<router-outlet>`*.

I tried to do the same thing and its works fine,

please check this live example and try to see if you have made any error in your code,

https://plnkr.co/edit/AYhau1gLYC7Flt4NknWa?p=preview

**app.approutes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent }  from './home.component';
import { MainCompnent }    from './main.component';
import {UserComponent} from './user.component';
import {FirstChildComponent} from './firstChildComponent';
import {SecondChildComponent} from './secondChildComponent'

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },


  { path: 'main', 
  component: MainCompnent,
  children: [
      { path: ':slug', component: SecondChildComponent },
      { path: '', component: FirstChildComponent }
    ]
  },


  { path: 'user', component: UserComponent }
];
export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```